# Log4j2: How to specify max number of copies to keep?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

In my project, I need to set up a Log4j2 configuration to generate a log file that is rolling every day.  Another requirement is to only keep a 2 days' log files.  So I have to restrict the total number of files to be kept in the system.  Following is what I got from my research, but it only restrict the number of files for each DAY, not the total number of files.  I am wondering if there is a convenient way to restrict the max number of log copies to keep?

```
<RollingFile name="DailyRollingFile" fileName="logs/audit.log"
append="false" immediateFlush="true" filePattern="logs/audit-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p [%t] - %m%n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
<Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</Policies>
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2" />
</RollingFile>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

In meantime, there is an feature request in the issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-435

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you direct this as a feature request to the Apache Logging mailing list ( https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/mail-lists.html ) or the Log4j-2.0 issue tracker ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2 )?

Answer (score 0):

The max number of files is also limited to the number specified in

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2" />
```

At the time of rollover,  only the specified number of files will be maintained. Older files will be rolled over. i.e. the total number of log files at any point of time will be the max value specified for the field DefaultRolloverStrategy.

With Log4j 2.5 onwards custom delete actions can be configured.Follow the details here.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover